# Шаблоны layouts android

Tags: android

Подскажите есть ли в сети тематические ресурсы с содержанием шаблонов лейаутов для андроид? Чтобы не верстать самому а использовать готовые варианты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению таких ресурсов не очень много. Как-бы вам не хотелось, но все что вы найдете придется допиливать до того состояния которое вам нужно. Решение вашей проблемы - находить библиотеки, открытые проекты, скачивать их и брать оттуда xml. Но на выходе не факт что вы получите адаптируемый шаблон. Вот к примеру есть [сайт](http://seotoolzz.com/free-android-app-templates/), где можно скачать как я уже говорил проект и посмотреть как и из чего сделан шаблон. Вот есть [сайт](https://www.template.net/design-templates/android-app-design-templates/) где можно просмотреть что вам нужно для примера. [Вот](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-free-Android-xml-templates) вопрос похожий на другом ресурсе, может там еще почерпнете нужную вам информацию.

Еще ресурсы: [ресурс_1](https://codecanyon.net/item/universal-full-multipurpose-android-app/6512720?_ga=2.248476036.2016354196.1571287904-842043952.1571287904), [ресурс_2](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/15-best-android-app-templates-of-2017--cms-29643), [ресурс_3](https://speckyboy.com/free-material-design-gui-templates-icon-sets/). Надеюсь что вы найдете ответ на ваш вопрос и решение проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: Ну если делимся сайтами, то вот ещё, https://www.uplabs.com/android https://appsnipp.com/